# Parámetro inválido en getSystemService

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Encontré el siguiente código en internet para verificar que haya conexión en mi aplicación Android.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // Si hay conexión a Internet en este momento
    } else {
        // No hay conexión a Internet en este momento
    }
```

Sin embargo, me aparece un error en 'getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE), dice que:

> getSystemService(android.content.Context,Class)in
>   ContextCompat cannot be applied to(java.lang.String)

¿Como puedo arreglarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta pasarle el contexto:

```
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    // Si hay conexión a Internet en este momento
     } else {
    // No hay conexión a Internet en este momento
    }
```